# Can't push github size limit

Tags: git, github

I installed GoogleMaps pod using Cocoapods. I tried commiting my changes and pushing to github. Then the size limit error popped up and I knew I had to keep the GoogleMaps folder in the gitignore file.

I added to my .gitignore file:
`Pods/GoogleMaps/`

In terminal:

```
git rm -r --cached . 
git add .
```

If I try to see if GoogleMaps folder is ignored I get this:

```
git check-ignore -v Pods/GoogleMaps         
.gitignore:1:Pods/GoogleMaps/   Pods/GoogleMaps
```

If I try to push to origin:

```
remote: error: Trace: c08289a82c9c540047ad0d396caa72f8f143a62e098c82c96a7de884eddf7c59
remote: error: See http://git.io/iEPt8g for more information.
remote: error: File Pods/GoogleMaps/Maps/Frameworks/GoogleMapsCore.framework/GoogleMapsCore is 134.89 MB; this exceeds GitHub's file size limit of 100.00 MB
```

Same problem with the size limit. Does anyone know how can I solve this?

EDIT:

I have tried
`git rm --cached Pods/GoogleMaps/Maps/Frameworks/GoogleMapsCore.framework/GoogleMapsCore`

And I get:
`fatal: specified route 'Pods/GoogleMaps/Maps/Frameworks/GoogleMapsCore.framework/GoogleMapsCore' folder not found`

EDIT 2:

I did git reset to the commit where I added these files. Deleted them and commit. Same message about the size limit. I can't understand why if I deleted the files before the last commit.

Comment: you can have a look over https://docs.github.com/en/github/managing-large-files/working-with-large-files

Comment: Move exact files whose file sizes are greater than 50 MB to the trash can, temporarily, for the moment.

Comment: If the file was added in a previous commit, you have to rewrite the history to get rid of that commit. I use BFG Repo Cleaner for that kind of job: `$ bfg --strip-blobs-bigger-than 50M  my-repo.git`

Comment: @jessehouwing The problem is that I did some changes to my code in that commit, apart from adding those files. Should I git revert to that commit and try to add the GoogleMaps directory again in the gitignore file?

Comment: I meant git reset! (Can't edit my comment)

Comment: You could `git revert --soft` (that should put the changes back in your working directory), add the `.gitignore` and commit again. Or do an interactive rebase, or use the BFG Repo Cleaner, as it will remove the files, but will leave the rest of the commit in tact.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Steps I took to solve the problem:

1. Reset to the conflicting commit (where I added the big files)
   `git reset --hard <commit_id>`
2. Remove the files from staging area
   `git reset HEAD Pods/GoogleMaps`
3. Remove files from index
   `git rm -r --cached Pods/GoogleMaps`

Then I commited and pushed the changes to my repository.

Answer (score 1):

Could you try this: `git reset HEAD Pods/GoogleMaps/Maps/Frameworks/GoogleMapsCore.framework/GoogleMapsCore`?

Comment: First I had to reset to the conflicting commit. Then I executed your command: git reset Pods/GoogleMaps/ and finally: git rm -r --cached Pods/GoogleMaps. Then I was able to commit and push the changes. :)